# YACC: Can I generate "syntax error" from my "semantic" processing?

Tags: syntax-error, yacc

I'm writing a program in YACC and C/C++. It parses a fairly simple grammar and stores the results in some tables.

I have rules like

```
room: DOTR ID roomname { AddRoom($3, $2); };
```

and the code for AddRoom is:

```
void AddRoom(const char* name, const char* id)  
{  
    theRoom = (void)new GameRoom(name, id);  
    if (!theGame->addRoom(theRoom)) {  
        ?????  
    }  
}
```

???? would be where I would insert code to generate a syntax error (I hope).

The purpose of this code is that every object in the game (rooms, doors, NPCs, things) has a unique ID. If `theGame->addRoom` detects that the ID is not unique, it will return false, and I want yacc to display an error message at that point in the input -- just as if an illegal token had been there.

Answer (score 1):

Just call `yyerror()`, and remember that there was an error so you don't proceed to later stages. But you do *not* want to treat this as a syntax error: otherwise you will cause the parser to start discarding tokens etc.

Comment: Thanks. This answers my question.  
  
Uhh... if I all yyerror that _won't_ make it start discarding tokens?   
  
Because you're right, I want to remember that I had an error(1), but I don't want to discard tokens.  
  
Just out of curiosity, what would I do if I _wanted_ to start discarding tokens?  
  
(1) I've added code to yyerror to set a global flag. If that flag is set, I won't generate the output.

Comment: D'oh!  Of course calling yyerror won't do anything to the syntax recognizer: the body is just a printf to generate the error message...